# Haskell -- parser combinators keywords

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators

I am working on building a parser in Haskell using parser combinators. I have an issue with parsing keywords such as "while", "true", "if" etc

So the issue I am facing is that after a keyword there is a requirement that there is a separator or whitespace, for example in the statement
`if cond then stat1 else stat2 fi;x = 1`
with this statement all keywords have either a space in front of them or a semi colon. However in different situations there can be different separators.

Currently I have implemented it as follows:

```
keyword :: String -> Parser String
keyword k = do
  kword <- leadingWS (string k)
  check (== ';') <|> check isSpace <|> check (== ',') <|> check (== ']')
  junk
  return word
```

however the problem with this keyword parser is that it will allow programs which have statements like if; cond then stat1 else stat2 fi

We tried passing in a (Char -> Bool) to keyword, which would then be passed to check. But this wouldn’t work because where we parse the keyword we don’t know what kind of separator is allowed.

I was wondering if I could have some help with this issue?

Comment: Just because a keyword is followed by a semi-colon, that doesn't mean it is being used correctly. Keywords are always part of some larger syntactic structure. Namely, a keyword is just a specific token which your grammar is built upon. The only difference between a keyword and an identifier is that the keyword is recognized by the grammar, rather than treated as a generic token left to later stages of parsing and evaluation.

Comment: The semi-colon itself is another token; you should have another combinator that recognizes correct collections of other tokens. (In this sense, the parser is really doing both lexical analysis--converting a stream of bytes into a stream of tokens--and parsing--converting a stream of tokens into an abstract syntax tree.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to handle the separators in `keyword` but you need to ensure that `keyword "if"` will not be confused with an identifier "iffy" (see comment by sepp2k).

```
keyword :: String -> Parser String
keyword k = leadingWS $ try (do string k
                                notFollowedBy alphanum)
```

Handling separators for statements would go like this:

```
statements = statement `sepBy` semi
statement  = ifStatement <|> assignmentStatement <|> ...
```

Comment: If you do it like this, the identifier "iffy" could be instead parsed as the keyword "if" followed by the identifier "fy". I believe (and I admit I'm totally guessing) the reason why OP decided that "after a keyword there is a requirement that there is a separator or whitespace" is to disallow this.

Comment: Oh i see, perhaps I missed that point in the question. I'll give it some thought and update my answer if I have anything to add.

Comment: I pushed a more complete example to https://github.com/steshaw/haskell-shebang-examples/blob/master/stack/imperative.hs